# SharePoint Online Disable Opening in client application

Tags: sharepoint-online

We want to force apply usage of office web apps only and not client application. We can change default open behavior to open in "Web App" only but still it shows "Open in Word" when we open in browser. Any way we can remove that totally?

Answer (score 0):

We can set the default open behavior for documents. When we change the behavior from open in the client application to open in the browser, the file will be opened in the browser by default when clicking the file link. But there is no OOB method to remove/disable “Open in Word” option.

To hide this “Open in Word” option, you may need code such as CSS or JavaScript.

In the classic experience, we can use the following script on the page to hide “Open in Word” option from context menu.

```
<style type="text/css">
li[aria-label="Open in Word"]{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

However, in modern libraries of SharePoint Online, we cannot edit the page and add custom code to hide this option.

Information about [customizing modern lists and libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries).

[Switch the experience from modern to classic experience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9) and use script.